# How to check the audio is stored locally and run it without downloading?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

In this code, the audio is downloaded every time when I click on a button. I want to do check audio stored locally. If stored as run it without loading. How can I do this?

```
  - (void) song{
NSString *stringURL = @"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B6zMam2kAK39VHZ1cUZsM3BhQXM";
NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
if ( urlData )
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"music.mp3"];
    [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

}

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"music.mp3"];

self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath] error:nil];
 }
```

Comment: apptality's answer solves your problem. However, I strongly suggest using the cache directory rather than the documents directory. Your app may well get rejected because of that as everything in documents may be backed up to iCloud and nothing that can simply be reloaded from the web should be backed up in the cloud. (Alternatively you can set some flag with your file that prevents it from being backed up. Unfortunately I do not have it handy. But using the cache directory is smarter and less code in the end.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSFileManager` has the following methods:

```
- (BOOL)fileExistsAtPath:(NSString *)path;
- (BOOL)fileExistsAtPath:(NSString *)path isDirectory:(nullable BOOL *)isDirectory;
- (BOOL)isReadableFileAtPath:(NSString *)path;
- (BOOL)isWritableFileAtPath:(NSString *)path;
- (BOOL)isExecutableFileAtPath:(NSString *)path;
- (BOOL)isDeletableFileAtPath:(NSString *)path;
```

So we check like this:

```
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"music.mp3"];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath isDirectory:NO];

if (!fileExists) {
    // start the download process here then save
    [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```